# Duplicate entries in prometheus

Tags: jenkins, prometheus

I'm using the prometheus plugin for Jenkins in order to pass data to the prometheus server and subsequently have it displayed in grafana.

With the default setup I can see the metrics at http://:8080/prometheus

But in the list I also find some duplicate entries for the same job

```
default_jenkins_builds_duration_milliseconds_summary_sum{jenkins_job="spring_api/com.xxxxxx.yyy:yyy-web",repo="NA",} 217191.0
default_jenkins_builds_duration_milliseconds_summary_sum{jenkins_job="spring_api",repo="NA",} 526098.0
```

Both entries refer to the same jenkins job `spring_api`. But the metrics have different value. Why do I see two entries for the same metric?

Comment: It seems that they aren't duplicates, one is just "spring_api" and the other has the "/com.xxxxxx.yyy:yyy-web" suffix.

Comment: I see these are only duplicating for maven jobs. Specifically, if I go to the folders under /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<jobName>. The duplicate entries correspond to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<jobName>/modules/com.xxxxxx.yyy:yyy-web. Not sure why they get created

Answer (score 0):

Possibly one is a a subset of the other.

In the kubernetes world you will have the resource consumption for each container in a pod ,and the pod's overall resource usage.

Suppose I query the metric "container_cpu_usage_seconds_total" for  {pod="X"}.

Pod X has 2 containers so I'll get back four metrics.

```
{pod="X",container="container1"}
{pod="X",container="container2"}
{pod="X",container="POD"} <- some weird "pause" image with very low usage
{pod="X"} <- sum of container1 and container2
```

There might also be a discrepancy where the metrics with no container is greater than the sum of the container consumption. That might be some "not accounted for" overhead, like maybe pod dns lookups or something. I'm not sure.

I guess my point is that prometheus will often use combinations of labels and omissions of labels to show how a metric is broken down.